# ASP.net Core MVC not calling System.Text.Json's custom polymorphic JsonConverter on abstract result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I have a .NET Core 3.1 controller derived from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase`, the custom json converter is not called on result output.

**IProduct**

```
public interface IProduct { ... }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IProduct Get(string id)
{
   IProduct product = _data.GetProduct(id);
   return product;
}

[HttpPut]
public Task Save(IProduct product)
{
    return _data.Save(product);
}
```

**JsonConverter**:

```
public class ProductConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<IProduct> 
{
    public override IProduct Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
         // this code works from unit tests, trust me :)
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IProduct value, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
    {
        // this code works from unit tests, trust me :)
    }
}
```

**Startup**:

```cs
services
  .AddControllers()
  .AddJsonOptions(options => {
      options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new ProductConverter());
  });
```

**Symptoms**

- When controller's action method `Save` is called, the `ProductConverter.Read` is called
- When controller's action method `Get` is called, the `ProductConverter.Write` method is **not** called
- I get json result of actual implementation of `IProduct`

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you ran it under your debugger? Are your breakpoints actually getting hit?

Comment: breaking at controller in both methods, breaking in read method of converter, but not in write method

Comment: This answer is old but I think it still applies: [Why when return interface in a web api method, I get the values of inherited class with interface values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19653031/3744182): *By the time it hits the Json serializer, it doesn't care what the return type of the method was. All it knows is "I have this object, let's see what I can do with it".* ...

Comment: Your converter isn't called because the actual, concrete type being returned isn't `IProduct`, so [`JsonConverter<IProduct>.CanConvert(objectType)`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonConverterOfT.cs#L53) returns `false`.

Comment: Try overriding `public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeof(IProduct).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert);`

Comment: tried. but due to logic in ProductConverter that defines the actual type first and then calls JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, actualTypeToConvert, actualProduct, OPTIONS) causes stackoverflow, unless i remove converter itself from the options)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, everyone! Would appriciate other ideas

Comment: @KirillShilin - Well that actually shows that overriding `CanConvert`  answers your question.  You didn't include implementations for `Read()` and `Write()` in your question, but to resolve the stack overflow, see [How to use default serialization in a custom System.Text.Json JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65430420/3744182).  Basically, cloning the `options` and removing the converter is the way to go.

Comment: _cloning the `options` and removing the converter..._ is the only solution i came with so far. Also considering creating custom output filter with ability to specify the converter explicitly.

Comment: You could also try wrapping the `IProduct` in some wrapper with the converter applied to the property, e.g. `public class ProductContainer { [JsonConverter(typeof(ProductConverter))] public IProduct Product { get; set; } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19653031/3744182) by [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) to *[Why when return interface in a web api method, I get the values of inherited class with interface values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19652862/3744182)* is old but apparently still applies to ASP.NET Core 3.1:

> By the time it hits the Json serializer, it doesn't care what the return type of the method was. All it knows is "I have this object, let's see what I can do with it".

Thus your converter isn't called because the actual, concrete type being returned isn't `IProduct` and so the base class implementation [`JsonConverter<IProduct>.CanConvert(objectType)`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/be19e1cc6aad0f28e3bf1d7c7201c455a96b3a9d/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonConverterOfT.cs#L53) returns `false`:

> ```
> public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
> {
>     return typeToConvert == typeof(T);
> }
> ```

To make your `ProductConverter` apply to concrete implementations of `IProduct` as well, override [`CanConvert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.canconvert?view=net-5.0) as follows:

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => 
    typeof(IProduct).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert);
```

Note that, if the implementations of `Read()` and `Write()` try to generate a "default" serialization of the incoming concrete product by calling the serializer recursively with the concrete type, you may get a stack overflow.  To resolve that, you could:

- Clone the options and remove `ProductConverter` from the list of converters as shown in *[How to use default serialization in a custom System.Text.Json JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65430420/3744182)*.
- Pass in default options rather than the incoming options as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59785679/3744182) by [Demetrius Axenowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4040476/demetrius-axenowski) to *[Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182)*.
- Wrap your `IProduct` in some container with the converter applied to the property, e.g.

  ```
  public class ProductContainer 
  { 
      [JsonConverter(typeof(ProductConverter))] 
      public IProduct Product { get; set; } 
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks the answer