# Force CamelCase on ASP.NET WebAPI Per Controller

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, camelcasing

In ASP.NET WebAPI, I know you can set the default json formatter to use camel case using [CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_camelcasing) in the global.aspx which will force ALL json serialization to camel case.

However, I need to be able to set it on a "Per Controller" instance, instead of a Global solution.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Thanks to @KiranChalla I was able to achieve this easier than I thought.

Here is the pretty simple class I created:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

public class CamelCaseControllerConfigAttribute : Attribute, IControllerConfiguration 
{
  public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
  {
    var formatter = controllerSettings.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().Single();
    controllerSettings.Formatters.Remove(formatter);

    formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
    {
      SerializerSettings = {ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()}
    };

    controllerSettings.Formatters.Add(formatter);

  }
}
```

Then just add the attribute to any Controller class you want CamelCase.

```
[CamelCaseControllerConfig]
```

Comment: I believe that this is a better solution that the one pointed to by Kiran.  Because this one removes and adds the formatter, it is controller specific.  When I used the example pointed to by the marked answer, it changes all my controllers to have the formatters, instead of being controller specific.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was exactly what I looked.

Comment: Brilliant approach, very useful

Comment: How can we implement this in .net Core?

Comment: @PrashanFernando (or anyone finding this answer) you can find details for .net Core here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56127866/516138

Comment: I've applied the same attribute but now it's applicable for all the controllers even I declared it above only one controller.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it's possible...you can use `IControllerConfiguration` to define per-controller specific configuration..

[This](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/ControllerSpecificConfigSample/ReadMe.txt) is a sample which describes this scenario. You can quickly take a look at how this interface should be used over [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/ControllerSpecificConfigSample/CustomControllerConfigAttribute.cs)(from the sample).

Answer (score 4):

This Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528779/use-camel-case-serialization-only-for-specific-actions) should be helpful. It shows you how to create an ActionFilter which can be applied to any action where you wish to use CamelCasing.

Comment: I looked at before and it is "Per Action". My question is, is it possible do achieve camelcase "Per Controller".

Comment: You can use this attribute at the controller and action levels. Although I would recommend adding the line - `_camelCasingFormatter.Indent = true` - to make the output more readable.

Comment: This is the best answer, imo

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old, but I had a problem with the accepted answer because there were other necessary changes to the formatter that were no longer present after removing and re-adding. I did this by just modifying the existing formatter as shown in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/mauricedb/5356933.