# Avoiding CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver for a specific method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, json.net, camelcasing

I have web api controllers and I am using this method of configuration in WebApiConfig file for camel casing my results for all controllers.

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Now I have a controller's method which is giving data to Angularjs translation provider and all translation strings are not in camelcase in my html, thats why I need results of that method to be not in CamelCase. How to avoid camel casing serialization behavior for this specific controllers' method.

Comment: This works good for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956838/force-camalcase-on-asp-net-webapi-per-controller

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use [ApiController.Json method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Web.Http.ApiController.Json%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).

just return like this from your controller method

```
return Json(data, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() });
```