# Is there a native object in the ASP.NET MVC assemblies that give access to the Formatters collection?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

In my MVC 5.2.7 project targeting .NET framework 4.6.1, I need to set the Json serializer settings to always to use came case.

So, I want to write in the `Application_Start` event something like:

```
HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
            new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Thing is: neither of the two `HttpConfiguration` nor the `GlobalConfiguration` classes are present in the MVC project.

I know that I can install the Web API related packages to get to these classes. The packages are:

```
1. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core; and
2. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost
```

But my question is: is there a native object inside MVC that gives me access to the `Formatters` collection without having to install these packages?

Comment: Did you already try the Filter provided in answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983350/specific-json-settings-per-controller-on-asp-net-mvc-6) ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari Please correct me if I am wrong but those components (ResourceExecutingContext, IResourceFilter, and the namespaces Microsoft.AspNet..) are in the .NET Core assemblies. I am talking about the .NET framework assemblies for ASP.NET MVC.