# How can I opt out of a JSON contract resolver

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

We have a Json.NET setup which sets the contract resolver to be the CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver. However, for some types I would like to opt out of the camelCasing behavior. Is it possible to do this by annotating those types in some way?

Comment: what version of .net are you using?

Comment: is this of any use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956838/force-camelcase-on-asp-net-webapi-per-controller you might be able to set the resolver per controller.

Comment: @Delosdos this is for a .NET 4.6 library, not for a specific web framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as of Json.Net [version 9.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/9.0.1) (June 2016), both the `[JsonObject]` and `[JsonProperty]` attributes support a `NamingStrategyType` parameter.  So you can use a `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` to set up the default naming scheme, but then opt out or even change to a different strategy using these attributes for specific classes or properties.

Here is a short demo:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo
        {
            CamelCasedProperty = "abc def",
            AlsoCamelCasedButChildPropsAreNot = new Bar
            {
                SomeProperty = "fizz buzz",
                AnotherProperty = "whiz bang"
            },
            ThisOneOptsOutOfCamelCasing = "blah blah",
            ThisOneIsSnakeCased = "senssssational"
        };

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            // set up default naming scheme
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public string CamelCasedProperty { get; set; }
    public Bar AlsoCamelCasedButChildPropsAreNot { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NamingStrategyType = typeof(DefaultNamingStrategy))]
    public string ThisOneOptsOutOfCamelCasing { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NamingStrategyType = typeof(SnakeCaseNamingStrategy))]
    public string ThisOneIsSnakeCased { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(DefaultNamingStrategy))]
class Bar
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "camelCasedProperty": "abc def",
  "alsoCamelCasedButChildPropsAreNot": {
    "SomeProperty": "fizz buzz",
    "AnotherProperty": "whiz bang"
  },
  "ThisOneOptsOutOfCamelCasing": "blah blah",
  "this_one_is_snake_cased": "senssssational"
}
```

Fiddle:

Comment: What if I don't have access to class Bar (because it's from 3rd party) but I actually want to force AlsoCamelCasedButChildPropsAreNot  to have all its  to have its properties CamelCase? Is there a way to do that just through attributes decorator? See [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326475/how-can-i-make-the-properties-of-sub-class-camel-case)