# Return TitleCase JSON from one API call, use camelCase on the rest

Tags: c#, .net, json, datatables

I currently have my web API set up to return all JSON in a camelCase format with the following code in `WebApiConfig`:

```
var formatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
            new 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

And it works wonderfully. However, I am using the jQuery Datatable plugin and am saving/loading the state through my API, and it requires the data to be returned in a TitleCase format. Now obviously I'm not going to rewrite my entire consuming application(s) to except TitleCase formated Json, so I need my `LoadState` route only to return TitleCase format.

I've tried things such as:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Controller/LoadState")]
public IHttpActionResult LoadState()
{
    var state = _eService.LoadState(UserProfile.IndividualId);

    //requires title cased object
    var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();

    return Ok(state);
}
```

But this seems to set the entire application to TitleCase and overwrite my settings in the `WebApiConfig`. Anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: See if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956838/force-camelcase-on-asp-net-webapi-per-controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{ 
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() 
};
// set any other settings here


return Json(state, serializerSettings);
```

The `Json` return method is what you want.  It lets you specify custom serialization settings *for that call*.

[MSDN Documentation for `ApiController.Json`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.json(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: @Halter No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation, I achieved this by doing some thing like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() }));
```

Hope this helps.