# Force SnakeCase Deserializing on WebAPI Per Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serialization, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

i want to change the incoming requests deserializing format just for one of my controllers. so i added this in to my `Global.asax` and it works just fine:

```
HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
    }
};
```

but it apply the changes to all of the controllers. i just want apply it for one of my controllers. i also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956838/force-camelcase-on-asp-net-webapi-per-controller) answer and i wrote this code according to that:

```
public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
{
    var formatter = controllerSettings.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().Single();
    controllerSettings.Formatters.Remove(formatter);

    formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
    {
        SerializerSettings = { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy() } }
    };

    controllerSettings.Formatters.Add(formatter);
}
```

but unfortunately it works just for serializing the outputs. is there a way to define it for deserializing inputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you need with a tricky media type formatter. Usually custom formatter  overrides methods `CanReadType()` / `CanWriteType()` and `ReadFromStreamAsync()` / `WriteToStreamAsync()`. `CanWriteType()` in your case should always return `false` since you are not intersted in customizing serialization. As regards deserialization you could use standard `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` (through inheritance or aggregation) and set its `SerializerSettings` to use `SnakeCaseNamingStrategy`:

```
public class SnakeCaseJsonFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public SnakeCaseJsonFormatter()
    {
        SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
            {
                NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
            }
        };
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Remaining part is applying of such custom formatter on controller level. You could do this with a custom attribute implementing `IControllerConfiguration` interface. In `Initialize()` method set your custom formatter at first position so that it takes precedence over standard `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`. You should not remove standard `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` because it will handle data serializing:

```
public sealed class SnakeCaseNamingAttribute : Attribute, IControllerConfiguration
{
    public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        controllerSettings.Formatters.Insert(0, new SnakeCaseJsonFormatter());
    }
}
```

Now just apply this attribute on controller you want and voila:

```
[SnakeCaseNaming]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear @CodeFuller. i did exactly what you posted but it didn't worked!! did you test the code? i guess we miss something.

Comment: Yes, I've checked and it works for me. What exactly does not work now? Have you removed customization of SerializerSettings in other places you tried?

Comment: SnakeCaseNamingStrategy doesn't apply to my inputs. i didn't remove ant thing. i just created a two classes (SnakeCaseJsonFormatter  and  SnakeCaseNamingAttribute) and apply the attribute on my controller. i can post my code but i guess its so obvious.

Comment: when i add SnakeCaseNamingStrategy in my global class it changes the properties name to snake case. for example FirstName become first-name. but when i add your attribute on controller. it didn't change anything.

Comment: Try setting breakpoints in `SnakeCaseNamingAttribute.Initialize()` and `SnakeCaseJsonFormatter` constructor. Are they called?

Comment: You wrote "it changes the properties name to snake case. for example FirstName become first-name". Are we still talking about deserializing? You send json with snake case naming and expect it to deserialize to usual naming, correct?

Comment: i add log to those methods and both called when i open mt help file:

Comment: [SnakeCaseJsonFormatter..ctor line:24;[];[here]

Comment: [SnakeCaseNamingAttribute.Initialize line:12;[];[here]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159830/discussion-between-david-and-codefuller).

Comment: Thank you so much dear @CodeFuller.