# camel casing json results only for a particular api call

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, camelcasing, controller-action

I am sending JSON result from my API in pascal case, but for only a particular web-api action I want to sent the response in camelCase.

I can do it globally using

```
 settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

But how can i do that only for a particular web-api-2 controller-action?

Comment: I am asking it for a particular action and not for whole controller, hence not a duplicate

Comment: That answer links to this answer: [use camel case serialization only for specific actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528779/use-camel-case-serialization-only-for-specific-actions).  Is this what you need?

Comment: thanks @dbc thats what i wanted